# Puppeteer page load event

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

The function on page load is not executed with the given syntax

```
 const func = () => console.log('PAGE LOG:')
    page.on('load',  func );
```

But is executed when written like this

```
const func = () => console.log('PAGE LOG:')
page.on('load',  func() );
```

In the documentation for puppeteer a given example was

```
page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));
```

Comment: Can you extend your post with what you wanted to ask please? It seems you've found yourself the answer that you need to invoke the function with paranthesis if you are composing the console.log's wrapper arrow function outside `page.on()`.

Comment: 1. `page.on('load',  func() );` may just seem to work as you call the `func()` unconditionally here, it logs before the listener is even set. 2. Do you call `page.on('load',  func );` before the navigation? There can be a race condition if you call it after `page.goto()`,